# Как ускорить парсинг BeautifulSoup через мультипроцесс?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, requests, beautiful-soup

Может кто подсказать, как можно ускорить процесс для ускорения парсинга?
В примере около миллион ссылок из сайта vimeo.com...

Мой код:

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

def main():
    time_start = time.perf_counter()
       with open('urls1.txt', 'r') as input_file:
        with open('result1.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
            for n, url in enumerate(input_file, 1):
                url = url.rstrip('\n')
                if not url:
                    continue
                try:
                    r = requests.get(url, headers={'referer': 'null', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64)'})
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
                    title = soup.select('head > title')[0].text
                    debug_str = f'Строка {n} - {url} - OK'
                except:
                    title = f'ERROR: {sys.exc_info()[0]}'
                    debug_str = f'Строка {n} - {url} - ERROR: {sys.exc_info()[0]}'
                output_file.writelines(f'{url}\t{title}\n')
                print(debug_str)
    time_end = time.perf_counter()
    print("Закончено за ", "%.2f" % (time_end - time_start), 'сек.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: А вы какие-нибудь вообще подсчёты делали - сколько у вас страница в среднем грузится? Я в том плане, что может вас и никакой мультипроцессинг не спасёт и ваш миллион ссылок будет до тепловой смерти вселенной качаться, даже если в 10 потоков сделать. Прежде чем что-то оптимизировать, нужно собрать хоть какую-то статистику и сделать какие-то прикидочные расчёты, чтобы понять, что именно нужно ускорять и стоит ли этим вообще заниматься.

Comment: Кроме всего прочего популярные сайты часто ограничивают либо общий трафик, либо число коннектов с одного IP, вам придётся какие-нибудь прокси прикручивать, чтобы обойти эти ограничения, в общем, всё может оказаться мягко говоря сложнее, чем вы думаете.

Comment: Скорость примерно 5000 ссылок за час